# Turtlebot Simulator SLAM problem

Tags: simulation, turtlebot, ros-fuerte, virtualbox, turtlebot-simulator

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear,

I followed the tutorial about building a SLAM map using Turtlebot Simulator. After creating the package, I type:

roslaunch turtlebot_gazebo_tutorial build_map.launch

But it says:

ResourceNotFound: turtlebot_navigation
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/home/viki/sim_workspace/unversioned
ROS path [2]=/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks
ROS path [3]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share
ROS path [4]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros

Would anyone help me? I am using VirtualBox OVA provided by Nootrix. Thank you very much.

David

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/51642/turtlebot-simulator-slam-problem/) by [Chik](https://answers.ros.org/users/3814/chik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 229 on 2013-01-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need install turtlebot_navigation.
Use command:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-turtlebot-apps
```

---

Originally posted by [Alexandr Buyval](https://answers.ros.org/users/691/alexandr-buyval/) with karma: 641 on 2013-01-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Chik](https://answers.ros.org/users/3814/chik/) on 2013-01-08**:
Thank you very much indeed. Now I face another problem which I posted in Turtlebot Simulator SLAM tutorial Problem of Gazebo. Hopefully you can take a look too. Thanks again.